# Julia: best way to sample from successively shrinking range?

Tags: random, julia, sample, sampling

I would like to sample `k` numbers where the first number is sampled from `1:n` and the second from `1:n-1` and the third from `1:n-2` and so on.

I have the below implementation

```
function shrinksample(n,k)
    [rand(1:m) for m in n:-1:n-k+1]
end
```

Are there faster solutions in Julia?

Comment: I don’t think that your function is doing what you’re saying but still what you’re asked by for is a faster way

Comment: @zombie fixed bug in my code

Comment: why not just `[rand(1:n-m)  for m in 1:k]` as your question says?

Comment: What will `n` and `k` be? Will `k` be small (compared to `n`)? How many samples would you take? These parameters are important for an optimization.

Comment: Primarily interested in n being large (2 billion in length) and k being close to n or equal to n.

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard `[rand(1:n-m) for m in 0:k-1]` ...

Comment: @Liso good catch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following takes ideas from the implementation of `randperm` and since `n` and `k` are of the same order, this is appropriate as the same type of randomness is needed (both have output space of size `n` factorial):

```
function fastshrinksample(r::AbstractRNG,n,k)
    a = Vector{typeof(n)}(k)
    @assert n <= Int64(2)^52
    k == 0 && return a
    mask = (1<<(64-leading_zeros(n)))-1
    nextmask = mask>>1
    nn = n
    for i=1:k
        a[i] = 1+Base.Random.rand_lt(r, nn, mask)
        nn -= 1
        if nn == nextmask
            mask, nextmask = nextmask, nextmask>>1
        end
    end
    return a
end

fastshrinksample(n,k) = fastshrinksample(Base.Random.GLOBAL_RNG, n, k)
```

Benchmarking gives a 3x improvement for one tested instance:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime shrinksample(10000,10000);
  310.277 μs (2 allocations: 78.20 KiB)

julia> @btime fastshrinksample(10000,10000);
  91.815 μs (2 allocations: 78.20 KiB)
```

The trick is mainly to use the internal `Base.Random.rand_lt` instead of regular `rand(1:n)`

Comment: Better add an `@assert` of `k<=n` too

Comment: @assert n <= Int64(2)^52 is to do with Floating point using 52 bits to store numbers?

Answer (score 1):

If this is not very sensitive to randomness (you're not doing cryptography), the following should be amazingly fast and very simple:

```
blazingshrinksample(n,k) = (Int)[trunc(Int,(n-m)rand()+1) for m in 0:k-1]
```

Testing this along with your implementation and with Dan's, I got this:

```
using BenchmarkTools

@btime shrinksample(10000,10000);
  259.414 μs (2 allocations: 78.20 KiB)

@btime fastshrinksample(10000,10000);
  66.713 μs (2 allocations: 78.20 KiB)

@btime blazingshrinksample(10000,10000);
  33.614 μs (2 allocations: 78.20 KiB)
```